# error while converting pem encoded certificate to der using openssl

Tags: security, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

when I try  to convert pem encoded certificate to der format , I am getting the below error.

> openssl x509 -in test.cer -inform PEM -out output.crt -outform DER

**`**unable to load certificate300:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE**`**

Help would be appreciated !.

Link to download the Test.cer [click to download](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS_VHzKcc-TOXJSNXBPcDg2QXM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you post the header of your test.cer please?

Comment: I have attached the Test.cer file as a link. Could you please try converting the file to other format? @DanielS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example CER you've provided is not in a format OpenSSL will accept.

OpenSSL expects PEM formatted certificates to have a maximum line length of 64 characters so you'll need to add a line break after every 64th character. Additionally, you'll want to add -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- as the first line and -----END CERTIFICATE----- as the last line. At this point the OpenSSL CLI will allow you to parse and convert the file to DER.

Be sure those begin/end lines have five dashes to start/end them or else you'll still get errors.

Comment: And if you care to know how many chars are on a line in a file this might be of use:

awk '{ print $0 " = " length($0) }' file

Comment: "a maximum line length of 63 lines"??? You mean characters I presume.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes haha, yes. A mistake 7+ years without correction! I've fixed it.

Comment: I've since looked it up and it should read 64 instead of 63 as well... sorry about the time warp :)

Comment: Off-by-one errors are a proud tradition in computing (fixed)